# Finding minimal number of modular multiplications.

Tags: number-theory

Question: Given integers a and b and assuming that the only operation available is modular multiplication, show how to compute, C = a^b mod p using the minimal number of modular multiplications.

Comment: There are lots of references at [A003313](http://oeis.org/A003313)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an answer that depends only on $b$ (various ad hoc shortcuts might be possible by exploiting the value of $a$ or $p$), then this is known as the addition chain problem.

It's safe to call this non-trivial to compute exactly for general $b$, although it can be approximated.  Knuth gives a fairly compact representation for $b < 149$ (can be found on this [informative survey page](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html)).  See [A003313](http://oeis.org/A003313) in OEIS for more references and tables of values.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
What if we convert b to binary?

Comment: @Siva Why would converting $b$ to binary make any difference to the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to express $b=\sum_{0\le r\le n}c_r2^r$ where $c_r$ are $0$ or $1$.

Then calculate $$a^{2^r}\pmod p$$ starting from $r=0$ using $a^{2^r}=(a^{2^{r-1}})^2$ and take the product of the residues where $c_r=1$

One example is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199547/use-lucas-test-with-a-7-and-prove-71-is-prime/199558#199558).

Comment: This is not the minimum number.  For instance, $a^{15}$ can be found in only $5$ multiplications by first computing $a^5$.  The naive binary method uses $6$ multiplications.

Comment: How have you computed $a^5? a, a^2,( a^3$ or $ a^4)$ then $a^2\cdot a^3$ or $a\cdot a^4$? What about $a^{15}?$

Comment: How about $a, a^2, a^4, a^5, a^{10}, a^{15}?$

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Help me if the condition is like b is binary.

Comment: @Siva:  if $b$ is a power of $2$, you get there with repeated squaring:  $a, a^2, a^4, a^8 \ldots$  You can always use the approach suggested here, but it may not be optimal.  $15$ is the first example where it is not, but there are many more.  Finding the optimum is not easy, and this approach doesn't seem much worse.